# SVN error running context: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: apache, svn, debian, hyper-v

I've created an SVN repo on my Debian Wheezy build server following [this tutorial](http://www.networkworld.com/article/2224093/opensource-subnet/use-subversion--apache--and-websvn-to-view-your-repositories.html).
`svn --version` gives `1.6.17`.

Sadly, I can't commit anymore to the repo from my Windows 7 machine; it fails with the following error message:

```
Transmitting file data .svn: E730054: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E730054: Error running context: An existing connection was forcibly closed
by the remote host.
```

I have had this error both with TortoiseSVN and the [command line client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/).

These are the contents of `/var/log/apache2/access.log` on the server for the time of the failed commit: [access.log](http://pastebin.com/dB8RufZM).
There is no entry for the same time in the error log.

I'm still able to check out the contents of the repo and `svn info http://myurl/svn/myrepo` works also fine.

The Debian server with the repo is running inside a VM on a Windows Server 2008 R2 (Hyper-V-Manager 6.1). The connection from my Windows machine to the Windows Server is established using FortiClient 4.2.8.0307.

After I ran into this error yesterday, I purged svn from the server and setup the repo again. This made the repo accept commits for a couple of hours until it failed again with the same error.

Currently commits work again with TortoiseSVN but fail with the [command line client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/).

What does `E730054` mean and how can I fix it for good?

---

I have upgraded to Jessie in the meantime, but the situation did not improve. Commits with Tortoise stopped working again, meaning that it hangs at the "Sending Content" action for about five minutes and then prints the error that's in the title.

Checkouts still work without a hitch, though.

`apache2 -v`: 
Server version: Apache/2.4.9 (Debian) 
Server build: Mar 29 2014 21:52:01

`svn --version`: 
svn, version 1.8.8 (r1568071) 
compiled Apr 1 2014, 03:41:42 on i486-pc-Linux-GNU

Here's a [thread](http://subversion.1072662.n5.nabble.com/Error-running-context-td176404.html) that discusses the error, but I could not conclude a solution for my problem from it.

---

I noticed that the problem occurs when I want to commit the *second* modification of a file.

## My fix

The issue went away permanently after using [`svnserve`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/svnserve) instead of `apache2`. [This tutorial](http://www.tonyspencer.com/2007/03/02/setup-a-subversion-server-in-4-minutes/) helped me set it up.

Comment: Switching to svnserve solved the problem for me too, thank you! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I was reading over the thread, it seems like some problems in the WEBDAV implementation on client site crashing the apache-thread. I had other issues with pre 1.8 repositories and I solved most of them by dump/reload the whole repository into a new one (using "**svnadmin upgrade**" is not sufficient!). Pre 1.8 repos have sometimes "corrupt/obsolete" data in revision files which is ignored by clients. It seems that this could cause the segfault.

You can dump/reload your repository like this:

```
svnadmin create newrepos
svnadmin dump oldrepos | svnadmin load newrepos
```

Note that it could take a tremendous amount of time to perform an update/reload cycle (approx. 1GB/h +- 50% depending mostly on disk speed).

If you have a different time, please post your time, I am doing a private research of dump/reload cycle performances.

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem with a single file while attempting to check in multiple files using Tortoise SVN on Windows 7 x64. Several attempts to commit the file using a variety of different versions of Tortoise SVN and the command-line version of SVN failed.

At the time, my laptop was using my home ISP internet connection. When I later went to work and attempted to commit the failing file from my employer's network, the file was committed without a problem.

I don't know why that was the case, but if you encounter this problem and find your way to this answer through a search engine query, you may want to try again – using a different internet connection. While not a solution to the problem, it may provide a temporary work-around.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error.

**Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote**

I am using the TortoiseSVN 1.11 version.
I am using checkpoint VPN, I simply restart my VPN connection

Answer (score 2):

I too faced the similar issue. 
SVN details: TortoiseSVN 1.12.0, Build 28568 - 64 Bit

Solution: Go to task manager and search for Tortoise SVN cache service, end this task and retry to update/commit the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error.

**Error running context: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote**

I solved this issue by switching the proxy to Cntlm and it works perfectly fine.
I am using TortoiseSVN 1.9.3 version.

Answer (score 0):

Hade same error. 
My problem was with Avast antivirus, when i put the url of the svn server in the exclutions the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem after our svn server migrated from lan to internet. At last, I solve this problem by **changing my IP Address**.

For Example: from 192.168.0.60 to 192.168.0.71.

> SVN Version: TortoiseSVN 1.9.7, Build 27907 - 64 Bit
>   OS Version: Windows 10, 1703

Answer (score 0):

I too had this issue in SVN client. I cleared the temp folders in windows. Then cleared all data including auth details from "saved data" in SVN settings. Then retried in SVN, it asked for authentication and it opened fine without any error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using VPN with CollabNet's SubversionEdge.

I simply enabled ***Subversion Server should serve via https*** in Configuration -> Server Settings and this solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this for myself by using Eclipse to commit (I guess that's Subclipse then) instead of Tortoise 1.8.11
I didn't try too many of the other answers first but I did reboot, try diff internet connections, and I tried end tasking the TSVN Cache service. None of those worked and didn't get around to trying others. I also tried deleting the entire folder locally, did SVN checkout and applied the exact same changes (merged in a few commits from trunk) and tried committing... still wouldn't work with Tortoise SVN but then I tried Eclipse and it worked immediately.

My next commit worked perfectly fine with Tortoise SVN. Not sure what the cause was.