# Cannot Checkout, "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

My SVN repo is on Cloudforge. I use VS2012 with AnkhSvn for dev. In my Windows Explorer, I am using TortoiseSVN v1.8.7

I am trying to "checkout" my entire project into a fresh folder. It has 2 folders, 1 for the web application, and 1 for the data layer code.

I right clicked within the empty folder and click on Checkout. All seems fine then it suddenly stops with the message:

```
Error retrieving REPORT: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I have Googled this widely experienced issue, but to no avail regarding a solution. Can you recommend some solutions to attempt.

Thanks.

EDIT1:

StackTrace received when attempting Checkout via AnkhSVN.

++++++++++++++++++++

SharpSvn.SvnSystemException: Error retrieving REPORT: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, SvnException error, Object targets)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, svn_error_t* error, Object targets)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.CheckOut(SvnUriTarget url, String path, SvnCheckOutArgs args, SvnUpdateResult& result)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.CheckOut(SvnUriTarget url, String path, SvnCheckOutArgs args)
   at Ankh.Commands.OpenFromSubversion.PerformCheckout(ProgressWorkerArgs e, SvnUriTarget projectTop, SvnRevision revision, String localDir)
   at Ankh.Commands.OpenFromSubversion.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__b(Object sender, ProgressWorkerArgs ee)
   at Ankh.ProgressRunnerService.ProgressRunner.Run(Object arg)

++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: Do you get the same error in AnkhSVN and TortoiseSVN?

Comment: I have now tried this from AnkhSVN via "Open from Subversion" which does a "Checkout" as well, but then got the error again, but this time with a StackTrace. See EDIT1. I have raised a ticket with Cloudforge.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, started happening after their latest migration on Aug 8th.

Comment: (...)"a new, more reliable Subversion service
architecture for Cloudforge.  We are in the process of migrating"(...)

More reliable my ass.

Comment: It's been 12 days since you reported this and I've just run into the same thing. CloudForge's response is that they are "working on it". Guess we're finding a new provider too

Comment: XP-Dev.com still working fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it worked with AnkhSVN previously and now suddenly stopped then the root cause is most likely on the side of CloudForge hosting. Contact their support or wait.

Comment: Thanks, I have raised a ticket now with Cloudforge. Getting the error with AnkhSVN, as well, points to a Cloudforge issue.

Comment: Now with CF, and they are still trying to resolve. I got issues with Commit as well.

Comment: CF on the case. However it prompted me to test another provider which is xp-dev.com which I am finding robust. Pricing seems sensible to.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error with subversion running on a local server at my office.  I was trying to get on it over VPN with tortoise svn.  I tried smart svn and got the same error....

Turns out I needed to forward port 1994 for OpenVPN on my router to my machine, giving my machine a reserved ip address and forwarding the port solved my problem.

No more error.

If you are running windows 10, chances are you'll need to forward a port for any VPN you might be using.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using VPN with CollabNet's SubversionEdge.

I simply enabled ***Subversion Server should serve via https*** in Configuration -> Server Settings and this solved the issue for me.

[I also posted this answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965847/svn-error-running-context-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-rem/58220851#58220851)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Apache, try to put this two lines

```
SVNAllowBulkUpdates Prefer
LimitXMLRequestBody 0
```

In your svn config file. Take a look in the following link

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Repositories_access_control_with_apache_mod_dav_svn_and_mod_perl